# Angular: Passing Data from A Component to B Component with EventEmitter - Issue with onLazyLoad Callback in PrimeNG p-table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm encountering an issue passing a string value from Component A to Component B in my Angular application. I'm using an `EventEmitter` to accomplish this. Here are my components and service:

**Component A (AComponent):**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../my-service.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  template: `
    <button (click)="sendCurrentFloorCode('FloorCode123')">Send Floor Code</button>
  `,
})
export class AComponent {
  constructor(private placeServices: MyService, private route: Router) {}

  sendCurrentFloorCode(floorCode: string) {
    this.placeServices.selectedFloorCode.emit(floorCode);
    this.route.navigate(['/inventory/list']);
  }
}
```

**Service (MyService) with EventEmitter:**

```js
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  selectedFloorCode = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

**Component B (BComponent):**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../my-service.service';
import { LazyLoadEvent } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  template: `
    <p-table
      #dt
      dataKey="id"
      styleClass="p-datatable-customers"
      [value]="allInventories.length > 0 || !loading ? allInventories : fakeData"
      [(selection)]="selectedInventories"
      [rowHover]="true"
      [rows]="defaultState.rows"
      [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
      [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50]"
      [lazy]="true"
      (onLazyLoad)="loadAssets($event)"
      [paginator]="true"
      [totalRecords]="totalCount"
      [filterDelay]="1000"
      (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
      (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)"
      (onHeaderCheckboxToggle)="selectUnselectAllRows($event)"
      (onContextMenuSelect)="onContextMenuSelect($event)"
      [contextMenu]="cm"
      stateStorage="session"
      [stateKey]="stateKey"
      (onStateSave)="onStateSave($event)"
      (onStateRestore)="onStateRestore($event)"
      [currentPageReportTemplate]="
        loading
          ? 'Yükleniyor'
          : 'Gösterilen satırlar: {first} ile {last} arası. Toplam: {totalRecords} satır.'
      "
    >
      <!-- Other HTML content of your p-table -->
    </p-table>
  `,
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedCurrentFloorCode: string | undefined;

  constructor(private placeServices: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.placeServices.selectedFloorCode.subscribe((value) => {
      this.selectedCurrentFloorCode = value;
      console.log('Received Data in B:', this.selectedCurrentFloorCode);
    });
  }

  loadAssets(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    // Now you can use selectedCurrentFloorCode and LazyLoadEvent
    console.log('Inside loadAssets:', this.selectedCurrentFloorCode);
    console.log('LazyLoadEvent:', event);

    // Run your code to load other assets here.
  }
}
```

As previously mentioned, the `p-table` component in the HTML of my `BComponent` is listening for the `(onLazyLoad)` event and calling the `loadAssets` function when pagination, sorting, or filtering occurs. However, the `selectedCurrentFloorCode` value still appears as `undefined` inside `loadAssets`.

Therefore, I need to ensure that `loadAssets` waits for the `selectedFloorCode` event to be updated and uses this updated value when that process is completed. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this waiting, and that's why I'm unable to solve this issue.

Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Comment: even emitting is used in components to relation to parent/child.  I see you have used subscribe in B component. that shows you had right intention :) just change to selectedFloorCode  to Subject(). yilmadan devam et ;)

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. However, I did try using Subject() before, and I encountered the same issue. Even with Subject(), I still face the problem of selectedCurrentFloorCode being undefined inside the loadAssets function.

To provide more context, I'm using EventEmitter to communicate between two components, and I've also attempted using Subject() as an alternative. Both approaches led to the same result, with selectedCurrentFloorCode remaining undefined in the loadAssets function.

If you have any further insights or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate them.

Comment: yeah you are using even emitter in wrong way. since you are routing after updating value, maybe try behaviorsubject.